# IE6 - Ordered List Bug on Print Stylesheets?

Tags: css, printing, internet-explorer-6

I've created a print stylesheet for a page with an ordered list (with numbers positioned outside) which contains list items housing various text and images. The content is printed as expected in "proper browsers" but the numbers disappear from the list items in IE6. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds as if it addresses your issue - http://haslayout.net/css/No-Bullets-on--ul--and--ol--Bug